# Include line breaks from sql database in printed div

Tags: sql

In my SQL database I have an entry that includes line breaks; it looks like this:

[image]

When I print in on my html/php page, however, all line breaks are gone:

[image]

This is the code I use to get it from the database:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while($item= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
   $item['comment']
}
```

How do I get the line breaks in the database onto the website?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following solution using [`nl2br`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while($item = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo nl2br($item['comment']);
}
```